# Convert html string to image for xamarin Ios

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I want to convert HTML string to image format for print receipt in Xamarin ios. Please any one convert below my code for xamarin ios. Thanks in advance.

```
 private Bitmap CreateBitmapImage(string html)
    {
        Bitmap objBmpImage = new Bitmap(1, 1);

        int intWidth = 0;
        int intHeight = 0;

        // Create the Font object for the image text drawing.
        Font objFont = new Font("Arial", 20, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

        // Create a graphics object to measure the text's width and height.
        Graphics objGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(objBmpImage);

        // This is where the bitmap size is determined.
        intWidth = (int)objGraphics.MeasureString(html, objFont).Width;
        intHeight = (int)objGraphics.MeasureString(html, objFont).Height;

        // Create the bmpImage again with the correct size for the text and font.
        objBmpImage = new Bitmap(objBmpImage, new Size(intWidth, intHeight));

        // Add the colors to the new bitmap.
        objGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(objBmpImage);

        // Set Background color
        objGraphics.Clear(Color.White);
        objGraphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
        objGraphics.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias;
        objGraphics.DrawString(html, objFont, new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(102, 102, 102)), 0, 0);
        objGraphics.Flush();
        return (objBmpImage);
    }
```

Comment: Some class? Please show the errors you get. Just saying "something doesn't work" is not a good problem description.

Comment: Bitmap, Graphics classes are not supporting in xamarin cross platform.
Actually I want to convert html string to image.
like below url
https://www.nrecosite.com/html_to_image_generator_net.aspx

Comment: with convert html string to image you mean that you want to get an image from the rendered html in a browser?

Comment: @Patrick yes I want to get an image from the rendered HTML in a browser.